# PostgreSQL- Function to update 3 shared columns from table B on table A

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

The main goal is to create a function that updates 3 columns on another table (the update of the 2 columns from the first table trigger the update on the second one).

```
CREATE TRIGGER                      trigger_modif_amount
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF net_amount, iva_amount
ON                                  erp.tb_lines
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE                   modif_amount();
```

The name of the 3 columns:  net_amount  , iva_amount , total_amount

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION modif_amount()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
UPDATE erp.tb_invoice
SET (net_amount,iva_amount,tot_amount) = (select COALESCE(sum(net_amount),0),COALESCE(sum(iva_amount),0),COALESCE(sum(net_amount+iva_amount),0) from tb_lines where invoice_id = coalesce(NEW.invoice_id, OLD.invoice_id))
WHERE invoice_id = coalesce(NEW.invoice_id, OLD.invoice_id);
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpsql;
```

The tables:

```
  CREATE TABLE erp.tb_invoice (
    co_code            CHARACTER(3) NOT NULL,
    invoice_id         INT NOT NULL,
    invoice_no         CHARACTER VARYING(15)  NOT NULL,
    cust_no            CHARACTER(5) NOT NULL,
    site_id            INT NOT NULL,
    payed              CHARACTER(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    net_amount         REAL NOT NULL,
    iva_amount         REAL NOT NULL,
    tot_amount         REAL NOT NULL,
    last_updated_by    CHARACTER VARYING(20) DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
    last_update_date   DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_invoice PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_company FOREIGN KEY (co_code) REFERENCES erp.tb_company (co_code),
    CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_customer FOREIGN KEY (cust_no) REFERENCES erp.tb_customer (cust_no),
    CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_site FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES erp.tb_site (site_id)  
  );
  

  CREATE TABLE erp.tb_lines (
    invoice_id            INT NOT NULL,
    line_id               INT  NOT NULL,
    line_num              INT NOT NULL,
    item                  CHARACTER(5),
    description           CHARACTER VARYING(120)  NOT NULL,
    net_amount            REAL NOT NULL,
    iva_amount            REAL NOT NULL,
    last_updated_by       CHARACTER VARYING(20) DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
    last_update_date      DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_lines PRIMARY KEY (line_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_lines_invoice FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES erp.tb_invoice (invoice_id)
  );
```

Comment: 1) Your `UPDATE` statement is wrong. It should be of form `UPDATE tb_invoice SET iva_amount=NEW.iva_amonut, ...`. 2) Look at [Trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) in particular `TG_OP`.

Comment: Hi Adrian. The result on the tb_invoice table is the same no matter what triggers the procedure. I suspect you wanted to put this to execute a different result if tg_op = update, right? Perhaps I'm not following you?

Comment: The idea is you write one trigger function and  use `TG_OP` to follow different paths depending on the operation actually run.

Comment: The operation to run is always the same! I specify the different possible situations in the trigger, but the procedure should run the code based on the 3 possibilities. I don't understand why the TG_OP use here, since it will update the other table no matter which of the 3 trigger situations happen

Comment: Because an `INSERT` does not an `OLD` row and a `DELETE` does not have a `NEW` row and you are currently using both in the function. You will have to 'shape' the function code for each type of operation, using the information that is available in each case.

Answer (score 1):

This trigger definition to only execute the function (modif_amount) if column (net_amount) and (iva_amount) is specified as a target in the UPDATE command:

```
CREATE TRIGGER                trigger_modif_amount
AFTER UPDATE OF net_amount,iva_amount ON tb_lines
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE             modif_amount();
```

This form only executes the function (modif_amount) if column (net_amount), (iva_amount) has in fact changed value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER                trigger_modif_amount
AFTER UPDATE
ON                            tb_lines
FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN ((OLD.net_amount IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.net_amount) AND 
       (OLD.iva_amount IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.iva_amount) )
EXECUTE PROCEDURE             modif_amount();
```

Comment: Thanks @valihan ilyasov, any way to add also the insert/delete part for the trigger to also work when this happens?

Comment: You want that trigger to start to work after inserting into these two columns or after deleting from these two columns?

Comment: I want the trigger to work if any of these 3 situations happen:                                         
  -Insert of row on table tb_lines,                                                                            
   delete of a row on table tb_lines,                                                               
   modification of fields iva_amount and net_amount on table tb_lines               That means if you modify a field that is not these 2 mentioned, the trigger should not work. So the update part does not apply to all the table

Comment: if you add INSERT or UPDATE it automatically will solve your need. Because  UPDATE [ OF column_name [, ... ] ] works only for the specific columns but INSERT or DELETE don't have a specification on columns

Answer (score 1):

You can create trigger which trigger after update of specific fields

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtrigger.html

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER test
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF net_amount, iva_amount
    ON tb_lines
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE modif_amount();
```

Updating overal sum in another table inside trigger is not a good idea (it moves business logic into triggers and is not save).

**Version 1**

```sql
update tb_invoice set
(net_amount,iva_amount,tot_amount) = (select COALESCE(sum(net_amount),0),COALESCE(sum(iva_amount),0),COALESCE(sum(net_amount+iva_amount),0) from tb_lines where invoice_id = coalesce(NEW.invoice_id, OLD.invoice_id))
where invoice_id = coalesce(NEW.invoice_id, OLD.invoice_id);
```

**Version 2**

```sql
update tb_invoice set
(net_amount,iva_amount,tot_amount) = (select COALESCE(sum(net_amount),0),COALESCE(sum(iva_amount),0),COALESCE(sum(net_amount+iva_amount),0) from tb_lines where tb_lines.invoice_id = tb_invoice.invoice_id)
where invoice_id = coalesce(NEW.invoice_id, OLD.invoice_id);
```

COALESCE in **sum** is needed to ensure, that even if invoice has no positions sums will be calculated as 0.

COALESCE in **where** is needed because during insert operation there is no OLD.invoice_id, and during delete operation there is no NEW.invoice_id.

My assumption is, that invoice_id cannot be changed. If not, that moving a position from one invoice to another should update ole and new one.

Comment: Thanks but the trigger will only work if insert or delete of net_amount and iva_amount? or it will work after insert/delete of a row on that table?  Also, the second part would be the procedure right? I need it to be the trigger

Comment: trigger calls the procedure or function, so in your case update should be in FUNCTION modif_amount().

Additionaly insert and delete always affect whole record. Insert introduces new values and delete operation delete record (and values).

You should read it as in Postgresql specification:
` (INSERT) OR  ( DELETE) OR (UPDATE [ OF column_name )`

Comment: Here I have a question. In the creation of the tables, for example, iva_amount from tb_lines is not a foreign key of tb_invoice.... So, in this case, we are doing the trick of connecting both tables with invoice_id, right?

Comment: We are not connecting tables in first version of update. It's just subquery not related with insert query (and we deliver to both queries the same `coalesce(NEW.invoice_id, OLD.invoice_id)`.

I updated my answer with second version, where invoice_id to subquery is taken from update query. 

Buut this is not connected with presence or absence of foreign keys.

Comment: And then how I make sure, for example, that all rows of field net_amount from table tb_invoice have the same value that the ones from tb_lines. Because at the end they should be the same.  That's why I spoke about foreign key, to understand the connection.

Comment: Not the same. As I understand one record in erp.tb_invoice table may be connected with few records in erp.tb_lines. So in tb_invoice we have sums of values from tb_lines

Comment: No, because you have the invoice_id. So for each id which is shared, the amount should be the same. We are only updating the value to make sure that both tables have the same values and not only tb_lines is updated. That's the idea behind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244556/discussion-between-grzegorz-kraska-and-jose-antonio-piedehierro-arias).